# Try to preg_replace section of url to use as php variable

Tags: php, magento, preg-replace

Our site has this call at the beginning to find the page's name (e.g. product.html, product = name) and adds '-tabs' to it to produce the variable $block_name:

```
    <? $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // this will return everything after the http://www.domain.xx including preceding "/"
$block_name = preg_replace ("/^(?:.*)\/(.*).html$/", "$1-tabs" , $current_url); ?>
```

The variable is then used to call a static block later with this:

```
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($block_name)->toHtml() ?>
```

It works fine if someone goes to http://example.com/product.html, but if I use any url tracking, like Analytics, and the url has this at the end:

http://example.com/product.html?utm_source=newsletter&utm_campaign=product_launch&utm_medium=email

Then the variable isn't created properly and the static block doesn't load.

Is there a way to ignore anything after the .html so that any tracking appending doesn't impact the static block loading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace("/^(?:.*)\/(.*).html\??.*$/", "$1-tabs" , $current_url)`

Comment: thanks, that worked (earlier comment was due to the fact that I was uploading the wrong template file)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) on the location first, which will strip off the get variables. From there, you can manipulate it as you currently are.

```
$pathOnly = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$block_name = preg_replace(...);
```

Comment: Tried this but it's not working, don't know if Magento has it's own version for PHP_URL_PATH

Comment: @Rick: I actually liked what another user posted, though appears to have been deleted since: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Try that over `REQUEST_URI` and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Will keep it in mind should I need it down the line, but the answer from nikhil500 got it working, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Magento and appear to be writing code inside a template you can do this:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('product');
if ($_product) $block_name = $_product->getUrlKey();
```

Several templates on the product page already define `$_product` for you which makes it even easier.

This way works when a page is requested the non-SEO way, such as "http://www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/123/", or when a category name is in the URL. `$_SERVER` could not handle these cases. Using an un-validated value from $_SERVER allows an attacker to insert values into your code which is definitely bad.

Comment: Thanks for the Magento specific reply.

Tried using the code, and yes the product page is already defined, I have:

`<?     $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
 if ($_product) $block_name = $_product->getUrlKey();
 $block_name = preg_replace ("/^(?:.*)\/(.*).html$/", "$1-tabs" , $current_url); ?>`

But when I add ?xxxx to the end of the url, the static block section doesn't loa

Comment: I meant to impress that you don't need `$current_url` nor `preg_replace` nor need to check for `.html`. The URL key is exactly what you entered for the product in admin and doesn't have the trailing `.html`.